# List is empty after filling, but spinner shows it has strings

Tags: java, android, list

I am fetching a JSON object and parsing it using GSON in AsyncTask.
After that, I pass the list from onPostExecute using a static void to a static list in my activity.

Then, I iterate over that list and fill in another list .
In onCreate, I adapt that list to the Spinner, and the choices show, but I can't select them.

When I try to use item 0 from that list, it gives me either IndexOutOfBounds - index 0, size 0, or it gives me a NullPointerException, depending on what I am doing, yet the spinner shows those items as existing. If I add an element using .add("something"), .size() returns 1, yet spinner shows more elements.

Here is the code:

```
    public  List<City> fetchedList = new ArrayList<City>();   //List that was fetched from JSO
public  List<String> cityList = new ArrayList<String>();  //List of cities derived from fetched list using getCity();
public static String[] countryList;                             //List that is fetched from strings.xml array

//Called from onPostExecute to fill cityList with cities
public void spinner(List<City> lista) {

    fetchedList = lista;
    for (City element : fetchedList) {   //For each City
      cityList.add(element.getCity()); //Get city name and put it into our list

         } }
```

Here is onCreate part:

```
   CityFetcher fetch = new CityFetcher(); // Do our asyncTask here
            fetch.execute();               // Run Forrest, run!

    countryList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, cityList);
    ArrayAdapter<String> stringAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countryList);
    origin.setAdapter(adapter);
    city.setAdapter(stringAdapter);
```

Comment: Check code in SetCity ().if in list there 'll b no values then it must be crashed with nullpointer exception.

Comment: But spinner shows it has values already.

Comment: Try and go through with the debugger, set breakpoints and step through the program watching your variables as they change.

Comment: Trying to, but can't figure out how to set breakpoints in android studio :\

Answer (score 0):

Your AsyncTask runs in background, so when you create your `adapter` from `cityList`, that list is empty.
Try calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` at the end of your `spinner(List<City)` method.

This is not related, but it may be a good idea to call `cityList.clear()` at the begining of `spinner(List<City)`, in case your task is called multiple times.

Comment: I can't call it at the end of spinner, since if I declare it ouside onCreate, it crashes with IllegalState. Tried to put it before setAdapter, but to no avail.
Also, thanks for the tip, will keep that in mind :)